# readRDS "Cannot read workspace version ..."

Tags: r

For months I have been working with a script which gathers a bunch of tweets with Rtweets, does an rbind, and then saves the output to an .rds file with saveRDS. Up until now, I had no idea of this "version=" argument so I was not including it. But since last week, I have a problem where when ever I execute:

```
file <- readRDS("file.rds")
```

I get the following error:

```
    Error in readRDS("bullshit.rds") : 
  cannot read workspace version 541346889 written by R 17741.73.84; need R 19777.84.83 or newer
```

I cannot figure out the solution. I saw something about updating packages, I tried that and it also was unsuccessful. I tried to find out which versions these are, but I cannot find any information about an R version 17741.73.84. I also tried with two different devices, and I got the same error.

Could anyone tell me what is going on, and how could I try fixing it? - It is more important for me to actually be able to read the file, and then I can try saving it on new ways, but the data is not salvageable if the file is lost (I will save it in multiple formats - learnt through the worst way i guess)

This is my current version:

```
    > version                                
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32               
arch           x86_64                           
os             mingw32                          
crt            ucrt                             
system         x86_64, mingw32                  
status                                          
major          4                                
minor          2.1                              
year           2022                             
month          06                               
day            23                               
svn rev        82513                            
language       R                                
version.string R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
nickname       Funny-Looking Kid
```

Comment: same problem, but no response ... https://community.rstudio.com/t/rds-file-read-error-cannot-read-workspace-version/123082 .  Any chance you're using the `golem` package? https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues/455  Similarly, anything where you're accidentally reading and re-writing the file in the wrong format could do that: https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues/455#issuecomment-728688499

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the answer. I checked the links you provided but I am not that sure it applies here. I was not using Golem and I was saving the RDS myself through saveRDS(appended_stuff, "file.rds"), so no packages in between. As for the reading and re-writing in the wrong format, I always use a reproducible script (select and run everything at once), so I don't see how I may have done that. Thanks for the help tho, the thread is useful.

Comment: Definitely seems like the files are getting corrupted somehow. The only other thing I can think of is to `find("readRDS")` and `find("saveRDS")` to make sure the read/save functions aren't funny versions coming from somewhere else ...?